# How to add regex expression to Sitemap.xml in laravel?

Tags: regex, laravel-6.2, xml-sitemap

How I can add regex expression to XML site-map so that I can cover all my routes.
These are my routes:

```
    Route::get('/page/{id}/customer','CustomerController@index');
    Route::get( '/post/{post}/book', 'PostController@book' );
    Route::get( '/post/{post}', 'Controller@show' );
    Route::get( '/post/{post}/{title}',PostController@title' );
    Route::get( '/post/{post}/{order}', 'PostController@order' );
```